# Ceiling light not turning on?

Tags: ceiling, light-fixture

My ceiling light is not turning on, not sure why? I switched off the circuit breaker where it is getting power from and have re attached the wires to the light fixture. Black wire , white wire and ground wire. When I turn the power on from breaker and I have a electrical current pen detector along the switch light and the the inside where the bulb goes in a light goes on my pen, that means there is power/ electricity. 
I'm putting in the right bulb but still not turning on. The wires are wrapped and topped off with cap. But not sure what the problem is ? Can it be the light fixture itself? I have had several instances from lightning and rain in the past shut off my power in the past, can it be from that ? 
Thanks in advance for advice

Comment: The light socket could be bent or otherwise bad, and sorry to be obvious, but the light bulb could be bad.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it's definitely not the bulb

Comment: it could be the neutral wire is broken your non contact tester can only see hot wires, the only way to find that out is to get a volt meter and measure at the socket no voltage then at the switch